# Running query in mssql gives error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, string-interpolation

When running `node.js` and `mssql` to query my database I can't get it to run. The string sent to the query ends up being just `S`. What am I doing wrong here?

This works:

```
const result = await pool.query`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects`;
```

This gives an error:

```
const query = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects';
const result = await pool.query(query);
```

The error is

```
RequestError: Could not find stored procedure 'S'
```

*Update*

The below works... why is that?

```
 const result = await pool.query([query]);
```

Comment: The query works just fine, which means you should check why *the Node code* trying to execete a stored procedure. You can check what is actually sent to the server by using SQL Server Profiler to capture queries, timings etc. Why did you use the `string-interpolation` tag anyway? Are you performing any string manipulation to generate the actual query? That's a *very* bad idea that can easily lead to SQL injection because eg the input text contained `'`. Someone could pass `'; drop table users;--` as an input. Or it could be `';exec s;` which woull lead to an error like the one you posted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos string interpolation just for the example. This is not production code. No, it does not work. When sending a simple string it splits on the chars but not when passing a string-interpolation.

Comment: splits how? where? If you have an issue with some code you should post *that* code. Somehow, somewhere you called `s` instead of that query.

Comment: No, `teadious` seems to expect an array. I still wonder why the string-interpolation version works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Seems I've learnt something new... passing `\`something\`` to a function will pass it as an array :)

Comment: If you want to see what is sent to the server use SQL Server Profiler, or Extended events. I'll bet you'll see an `exec s;` or `exec sp_executesql 's'`. As for what's going on, I'd guess ` pool.query(query)` treated `query` as a char array and tried to send individual characters. Why? Which packages and versions did you use? Most `tedious` examples *don't* call `query` directly, they create a Request object

Comment: Alot of new stuff in node.js that I'll need to catch up on. I actually already switched to creating a request. I just got my current code from an example and didn't really know about the backtick thing. Thanks.

Comment: Fyi; the example is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals

Comment: I'd suggest you check [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017)'s and [node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#documentation)'s examples first. As for backticks, they aren't a way to pass arrays, they define [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for use with  ... string interpolation. Which, btw should not be used with SQL becaues it's a lot easier to use parameters

Comment: As for that example, I *hate* interpolatey parameterized strings. It's far too easy to use them as plain old strings, eg by defining them in a previous line. `sql.query\`select * from mytable where id = ${value}\`` is not the same as `query=\`select * from mytable where id = ${value}\`sql.query(query)`. In the first case you pass a query template and parameters to `query` allowing it to extract the parts and create a proper parameterized query. In the second you pass just a string that's fully susceptible to injection attacks.

Comment: btw I made that mistake just this Friday, even though I *do* know about the problem. And I still did it. I only found out about the actual problem when I checked the actual query and show it contained the verbatim string instead of a query+parameters. Luckily, I use [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler) to check perf and queries.

Answer (score 0):

call request,then call query.

```js
connection = await sql.connect(DB_CONFIG)
let request = await connection.request() // call this
let data = await request.query(selectSQL)
```